# Viewing & Geometrical Transformations in R

Tags: r

I am a graphics programmer from the GKS days trying to use R graphics. I have two questions that relate to transformations in R:

1. I was wondering if there is an equivalent for building a viewing pipeline in R where one could map a window in world coordinates [wc] to a viewport in device coordinates [dc]. For example I could specify a transofrmation t which maps a window of (wcxmin, wcxmax, wcymin, wcymax) to (vpxmin, vpxmax, vpymin, vpymax) where wc is (1000, -50, 40, 90) and vp is (0, 800, 0, 600). The objective being that all graphics calculations are done in wc but the graphics engine renders it in dc. In this case it would scale the coordinates appropriately and also flip the x-axis as wcxmin > wcxmax.
2. Is there an equivalent of graphics segments which could then be transformed [sclae, shift, rotate, and possibly shear] via a transformation matrix.

I am sure I am missing something very basic in R graphics. I could successfully build such transforms in SVG without any issues. I have been looking at packages like grid, lattice, ggplot2 but have not been able to make much progress.

Thanks.

Here's some sample code for something I am trying to do:

```
distn<-rnorm(100)
distw<-rweibull(100, shape=2)
dret<-stack(list(norm=distn, weib=distw))
n<-0
for (idx in levels(dret$ind)) {
        pct<-dret[dret$ind == idx,c('values')]
        # scale and shift the data
        pct<-(pct-min(pct))/(max(pct) - min(pct))
        if (n == 0) {
                # top left
                par(fig=c(0,0.5,0.5,1))
                limx<-c(0,1)
        } else  {
                # bottom right
                par(fig=c(0.5,1,0,0.5), new=TRUE)
                limx<-c(1,0)
        }
        fp<-density(pct)
        sfx<-fp$x
        sfy<-(fp$y-min(fp$y))/(max(fp$y)-min(fp$y))
        sortpct<-sort(pct)
        ecdfpct<-(1:length(sortpct))/length(sortpct)
        plot(sortpct, ecdfpct, xlim=limx, type="l", col="green")
        lines(sfx, sfy, xlim=limx, type="l", col="red")
        n<-n+1
}
```

I would like to rotate the figure in the bottom right quadrant by -90 degrees.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own plotting device for R? What keeps you from using the existing graphics engines?

Comment: @shujaa, I am not trying to create a new plotting device. Please see the sample code that I added to the post to illustrate a plot rotation issue. Could you recommend some graphics engine that might have the features I am looking for?

Comment: The package `gridExtra` can do this.  see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-June/280949.html) for an example.

Comment: To rotate (-)90 degrees you just swap the x and y arguments.

Comment: [Another page](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e2/help/06/09/0447.html) shows how to do it without `gridExtra`.

Comment: @Dwin, Thanks for that tip which does provide a workaround for this specific case -- with the change that limx<-(0,1) unconditionally. Justin/nograpes, I will try and use gridExtra for more general purpose work though I still need to research the viewing transformation issues. Probably viewport will help address them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'grid' package does that all the time. The viewports are represented as [0,  1] in both X and Y directions(and sometimes Z) and the functions `convertX` and `convertY` are called to move from user-coordinates to grid-coordinates. Type `help(grid)` for a full list of facilities. A third dimension is also represented when using wireframe or levelplot. Transformations via homogeneous coordinates are accomplished via 4 x 4 matrices stored as an item accessed as `current.transform( current.viewport())`. You can get more detail regarding how those transformation matrices are handled in R by looking at the code in `trans3d`. I see that @nograpes has already pointed you to the high-level rotation facility in the `grid::pushViewport` function.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. What I had been missing was the xscale and yscale parameters of the viewport call which allow you to map a user-coordinate space into a normalized unit (1x1) space.